# Best software to create alphabet chart

Tags: text, software-recommendation, composition, posters

[image]

I am interested in creating a personalized version of this alphabet chart.  I am a complete novice and would like to play around with creating it myself.  Can someone please tell me if there is an easy way to create this?  Or if there is a particular software that would make it feasible?

I tried to create it on Word with text boxes but it wasn't the easiest to maneuver.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no software apart from Word, then you might like to try some free software such as Inkscape(dot)org. It's a free and OpenSource vector image editor.  There is a bit of a learning curve if you are prepared to learn. However it's easy enough to switch on the grid, and the snap to grid to draw rectangles that butt up against each other, then fill them with colour, and easy enough to type text, recolour it, change the font, rescale, and move them around, rotate them, etc.

Here's a screenshot of Inkscape, this took me about 5 minutes to make.

[image: Screenshot of Inkscape]

Comment: Thank you!  I am willing to learn and this is exactly what I was hoping was out there.  Thanks again.